# locale in laravel 5.4 returns to the pervious locale after refresh

Tags: php, laravel, localization, locale

im learning the multi locale inn laravel 5.4 
so
i created two files 
first one in resources/lang/es/greeting.php

```
<?php

return [

    'hello' => 'hola',

];
```

and second  in resources/lang/en/greeting.php

```
<?php

return [

    'hello' => 'hola',

];
```

and i created this route inside web.php

```
Route::get('/{locale}', function ($locale) {
    App::setLocale($locale);
    return view('index');

});
```

so when i request this link  (localhost:8000/es)
it works 
but when i refresh the page its returns to default locale which is en

and i want it to stay in the new locale 
so help me please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set the locale permanently for that session, change the route code to:

```
Route::get('/{locale}', function ($locale) {
    App::setLocale($locale);
    Session::put('locale', $locale);
    return view('index');
});
```

Then add a middleware to check if session has locale, and if so set the locale like so:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
    if(Session::has('locale')) {
        app()->setLocale(Session::get('locale'));
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: i did what you said but i still have the same problem

Comment: Can you post your entire middleware code along with kernel.php? I'm assuming you registered the middleware and used the middleware in your routes

Comment: this web.php 

<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});
Route::get('/test', function () {
    return view('test');
});

Route::get('/{locale}', function ($locale) {
    App::setLocale($locale);
    Session::put('locale', $locale);
    return view('index');
})->middleware('lang');

Comment: kernel.php
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'lang' => \App\Http\Middleware\Checklang::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    ];

Comment: middleware

<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

use Session;
class Checklang
{
-
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
           if(Session::has('locale')) {
              app()->setLocale(Session::get('locale'));
            }
            return $next($request);
    }
}

Comment: The middleware doesnt need to be applied to the route that changes the language. It needs to be applied to **all the other** routes!