# Laravel 5.4 Locale restores to default when using redirect()

Tags: redirect, routes, localization, laravel-5.4

I'm struggling with the Laravel's locale on Fresh new Project. I googled many times, but they didn't solve my problem.

Then I followed [locale in laravel 5.4 returns to the pervious locale after refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42564065/locale-in-laravel-5-4-returns-to-the-pervious-locale-after-refresh) source, but it works only when I call pages by **view**

```
  return view('home');
```

And it does not work when I use **routes**

```
  return redirect()->route('home');
```

Here are my files:

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/lang/{locale}', function ($locale) {
    App::setLocale($locale);
    Session::put('locale', $locale);
    //return view('home');                         ###### This one works
    return redirect()->route('home');              ###### Where as this does NOT work
});

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

**home.blade.php**

```
<div class="panel-body">
    You are logged in!
    {{__('auth.success')}}
    <br>
    <a href="/lang/ru">Rus</a>
    <br>
    <a href="/lang/kg">Kgz</a>
</div>
```

**ChangeLocale.php** Middleware (I call it for every request of pages)

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(Session::has('locale')) {
        app()->setLocale(Session::get('locale'));
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Thanks in advance ;)

Ok, after I changed

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

**to**

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home')->middleware('changeLocale');
```

It started to work.

So, why my Middleware, is not working?

Should I assign middleware seperately to all my routes?

Comment: Create a route group that applies the middleware to routes other than `lang/{locale}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add your `changeLocale` middleware to `web` group in `app/Http/Kernel.php`:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        ...
        \Your\ChangeLocateMiddleware::class
    ],
    ...
]
```

As you may see in `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php`, this middleware group applies to all your `web` routes.